# Construct left and right adjoints to $ob: Cat \to Sets$

Tags: category-theory

This question is exercise 4.1.ii form Riehl's category theory in context:

> Let  $ob: Cat \to Sets$ be the functor that sends a category to its set of objects. Construct left and right adjoints to this functor.

My guess is that the two functors we need construct should be: the functor sending a set $S$ to the category whose objects are $S$ and the only morphisms are idenitity morphisms, and the functor sending $S$ th the category whose objects are $S$ by it has `all' morphisms in some sense.

I'm not sure if the idea of having `all' morphisms is correct. In the case this is correct, I am not sure how to make this precise.

Comment: I think your first functor should be correct. For the other one you need to build a free category of some graph with "all" arrows whatever that means. Maybe it helps to think that you need a canonical image for each possible arrow between your objects such that it commutes with all other images of possible arrows.

Comment: @linkja It is not a _free_ category on a graph. (Composition will not be free.)

Comment: @Zhen Li then I think I have misunderstood free categories. But it should be the category with all the objects and unique arrows between each two objects right, so for each possible choice of domain and codomain exactly one arrow? So the problem with the free category is that you would have to many morphims?

Comment: Yes, the free category on a graph would have too many morphisms (or not enough).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we have an embedding $\mathrm{Set} \xrightarrow{D} \mathrm{Cat}$, which sends a set to a discrete category. For any small category $\mathcal C$, a functor $F: DS \rightarrow \mathcal C$ is just a function on underlying set of objects, as the only arrows are identities, which image is forced. Thus we get the right adjoint
$$\operatorname{Funct}(DS, \mathcal C) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(S, ob(\mathcal C))$$

Now consider a function $f: ob(\mathcal C) \rightarrow S$. The functor $\mathcal C \rightarrow \mathcal D$ correspondending to $f$ can simply taken to be $f$ on sets of objects and trivial on arrows. There is only one canonical codomain category making it possible, the full category $FS$ on $S$, where each pair of objects are connected with unique arrow, so the induced value of a functor on arrows is uniquely determined, thus trivial. This isomorphism provides the other adjoint, as we have

$$\operatorname{Funct}(\mathcal C, FS) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}(ob(\mathcal C), S)$$

Comment: By discrete category, you mean $DS$ only has identity morphisms?

Comment: Yes. Since each identity must be mapped by a functor to identity, the functor is uniquely determined by its values on objects